# Can't get yum repository (ius) to install because of (epel) dependency that seems to be installed

Tags: yum, chef, dependencies, epel

So I'm trying to install the epel repository and then also install the ius repository.

I'm managing this server with chef, and my run list goes

```
...
"recipe[yum::yum]",
"recipe[yum::epel]",
"recipe[yum::ius]",
...
```

And it installs the epel repository correctly, contents of `epel.repo` in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

```
# Generated by Chef for chef-test.midwestern.de
# Local modifications will be overwritten.
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
enabled=1
```

and it shows as enabled for `yum repolist all`

but when I do this

```
rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
```

It outputs this

```
warning: /var/chef/cache/ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 9cd4953f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    epel-release is needed by ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el6.noarch
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To supplement what NickW said, I'd debate whether you *have* installed the dependency.

You're using chef to spraypaint a new dot-repo file into the system.  While that's neat, that's semantically identical to hand-copying a dot-repo file into the system, and you'd never responsibly do that.  Neither of those actions actually install an RPM dependency:  they're just copying files into the system in a barely- or un-trackable manner, since they don't register the copied file with the system-wide meta-info database which is used exclusively and expressly for dependency calculation.  And that's why, despite your chef recipe installing a file into the system, its contents tracked in the third-party chef checksums database, you are still running into dependency issues.

I use chef.  It's a fine tool.  As it's very effective at allowing us to do well or poorly at vast scale, don't forget you're still managing Linux.

SF won't let me comment properly as I lack the 50 magic beans.

Answer (score 0):

Install the epel-release package, obviously:

For the 5 series
`http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/repoview/epel-release.html`

For the 6 series
 `http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html`